# How to append list of string to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div:

```
<div id="cmplList" data-date="09/2017"></div>
```

And this method:

```
function test(data) {       

            jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
              $('#cmplList').append($("ul").append($("<li>").text()));
        });
}
```

The `data` variable is string array.

I try to create `ul li` element and append it to `div`.But, it seems that I do it wrong, any idea what I do wrong in code above?

Comment: it's working for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append `ul` **DOM** element to your `div` outside of the `each` function.

In the other hand, you have to create `ul` firstly and then `append` it to your **div**.

```
<div id="cmplList" data-date="09/2017"></div>
function test(data) {
    var ul=$("<ul>");
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
          ul.append($("<li>").text(value));
    });
    $('#cmplList').append(ul);
}
```

Short example:

```js
var data = ['1','2'];
function test(data) {
        var ul=$("<ul>");
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
              ul.append($("<li>").text(value));
        });
        $('#cmplList').append(ul);
}
test(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cmplList" data-date="09/2017"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the UL, then the LI, and set the LI's text, and then append it all to the DIV

```js
function test(data) {

  var ul = $('<ul />');

  jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    ul.append( $('<li />', {text: value}) );
  });

  $('#cmplList').append( ul );
}

var data = ['test','test2'];

test(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cmplList" data-date="09/2017"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Vanilla version

```
var data = ['A','B','C']

var ul = document.createElement('ul');

data.forEach(function(str){
   ul.innerHTML += '<li>'+str+'</li>'
}

document.querySelector('#cmplList').appendChild(ul);
```

or a one liner for that matter

```
document.querySelector('#cmplList').innerHTML = '<ul><li>'+['A','B','C'].join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul>';
```

The same one liner with jquery

```
$('#cmplList')[0].innerHTML = '<ul><li>'+['A','B','C'].join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function test(data) {

        var ul = $('<ul />');

        jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
             ul.append( $('<li />', {text : value}) );
        });

        $('#cmplList').append(ul); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ul and append li into it and than append the created ul to div.

```
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];
// create ul
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");

$.each(data, function(i, value){
  // creating list item and appending it to the ul
  var li = $("<li>" + value + "</li>");
  ul.append(li);
});
// appending the ul to div
$("#cmplList").append(ul);
```